# Is there a Sign-up/Sign-in GUI functionality for AWS Cognito web apps (not mobile apps)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

I am aware AWS has sign-in UI for ios and android apps, But is there a similar functionality for web apps as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean sample Apps, indeed for ios and android, we have provided sample apps for user pools (if that is the service you are looking for). For Javascript, there are a couple that either external developers or solutions architects have written. Links below:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cognito-angular2-quickstart

https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/123

Comment: I have an issue regarding sample App in android Please look at the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541585/login-issue-in-amazon-mobile-hub-with-cognito