# Login Issue in Amazon Mobile Hub with Cognito

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub, amazon-cognito-facebook

I am using Mobile Hub (amazon) in my android project and for sign-in providers i am using cognito and I have their sample code which they provide and I modify the code and the Login with Facebook is working but the issue which I am facing is `onSuccess` method when user login successfully called twice and I debugg it but I can not Figure it out how to fix that issue.

**SplashActivity.java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SignInResultHandler {

    IdentityManager identityManager;
    private LottieAnimationView animationView;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = SplashActivity.class.getSimpleName() + " : ";
    private final StartupAuthResultHandler authResultHandler = new StartupAuthResultHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(final StartupAuthResult authResult) {
            identityManager = authResult.getIdentityManager();
            if (authResult.isUserSignedIn()) {
                // User has successfully signed in with an identity provider.
                final IdentityProvider provider = identityManager.getCurrentIdentityProvider();
                Logger.d(LOG_TAG + "Signed in with " + provider.getDisplayName());
            } else if (authResult.isUserAnonymous()) {
                // User has an unauthenticated anonymous (guest) identity, either because the user never previously
                // signed in with any identity provider or because refreshing the provider credentials failed.
                // Optionally, you can check whether refreshing a previously signed in provider failed.
                final StartupAuthErrorDetails errors = authResult.getErrorDetails();
                if (errors.didErrorOccurRefreshingProvider()) {
                    final AuthException providerAuthException = errors.getProviderRefreshException();
                    Logger.d(LOG_TAG + String.format(
                            "Credentials for Previously signed-in provider %s could not be refreshed." +
                                    providerAuthException.getProvider().getDisplayName()) +
                            providerAuthException);
                }
                Logger.d(LOG_TAG + "Continuing with unauthenticated (guest) identity.");
            } else {
                // User has no identity because authentication was unsuccessful due to a failure.
                final StartupAuthErrorDetails errors = authResult.getErrorDetails();
                Logger.e(LOG_TAG + "No Identity could be obtained. Continuing with no identity.",
                        errors.getUnauthenticatedErrorException());
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        animationView = (LottieAnimationView) findViewById(R.id.animation_view);
        identityManager = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getIdentityManager();
        identityManager.doStartupAuth(this, authResultHandler);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (identityManager.isUserSignedIn()) {
                    goMain();
                } else {
                    goSignIn();
                }
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        animationView.setProgress(0f);
        animationView.playAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        animationView.cancelAnimation();
    }


    /**
     * Go to the main activity.
     */
    private void goMain() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    private void goSignIn() {
        identityManager.signInOrSignUp(this, this);
        finish();
    }

     /* This method is called two times and I also search in code it inoke only one time*/
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Activity callingActivity, IdentityProvider provider) {
        callingActivity.finish();
        if(provider != null) {
            IdentityProfile identityProfile = identityManager.getIdentityProfile();
            Logger.d(LOG_TAG + " Name : " + identityProfile.getUserName());
            Logger.d(LOG_TAG + " Email : " + identityProfile.getUserEmailAddress());
            Logger.d(LOG_TAG + " ImageLink : " + identityProfile.getUserImageUrl());
            Logger.d(LOG_TAG + " provider : " + provider.getProviderType());
        }
        goMain();
    }

    /**
     * User cancelled signing in with a provider on the sign-in activity.
     * Note: The user is still on the sign-in activity when this call is made.
     *
     * @param provider the provider the user canceled with.
     */
    public void onIntermediateProviderCancel(Activity callingActivity, IdentityProvider provider) {
        Logger.d(LOG_TAG + "onIntermediateProviderCancel() called with: callingActivity = " +
                "[" + callingActivity + "], provider = [" + provider + "]");
    }

    /**
     * User encountered an error when attempting to sign-in with a provider.
     * Note: The user is still on the sign-in activity when this call is made.
     *
     * @param provider the provider the user attempted to sign-in with that encountered an error.
     * @param ex       the exception that occurred.
     */
    public void onIntermediateProviderError(Activity callingActivity, IdentityProvider provider, Exception ex) {
        Logger.d(LOG_TAG + "onIntermediateProviderError() called with: callingActivity = [" + callingActivity + "], " +
                "provider = [" + provider + "], errorMesage = [" + ex.getMessage() + "]");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCancel(Activity callingActivity) {

        return false;
    }

}
```

**SignInActivity.java**

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = SignInActivity.class.getSimpleName() + " : ";
    private SignInManager signInManager;

    /**
     * SignInProviderResultHandlerImpl handles the final result from sign in.
     */
    private class SignInProviderResultHandlerImpl implements SignInProviderResultHandler {
        /**
         * Receives the successful sign-in result and starts the main activity.
         *
         * @param provider the identity provider used for sign-in.
         */
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final IdentityProvider provider) {
            Logger.d(LOG_TAG + String.format("Sign-in with %s succeeded.", provider.getDisplayName()));

            // The sign-in manager is no longer needed once signed in.
            SignInManager.dispose();

            final IdentityManager identityManager = signInManager.getIdentityManager();
            final SignInResultHandler signInResultsHandler = signInManager.getResultHandler();
            // Load user name and image.

            identityManager.loadUserIdentityProfile(provider, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Call back the results handler.
                    signInResultsHandler.onSuccess(SignInActivity.this, provider);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Receives the sign-in result indicating the user canceled and shows a toast.
         *
         * @param provider the identity provider with which the user attempted sign-in.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCancel(final IdentityProvider provider) {
            Logger.i(LOG_TAG + String.format("Sign-in with %s canceled.", provider.getDisplayName()));
            signInManager.getResultHandler().onIntermediateProviderCancel(SignInActivity.this, provider);
        }

        /**
         * Receives the sign-in result that an error occurred signing in and shows a toast.
         *
         * @param provider the identity provider with which the user attempted sign-in.
         * @param ex       the exception that occurred.
         */
        @Override
        public void onError(final IdentityProvider provider, final Exception ex) {
            Logger.d(LOG_TAG + String.format("Sign-in with %s caused an error." +
                    provider.getDisplayName()) + ex);
            signInManager.getResultHandler().onIntermediateProviderError(SignInActivity.this, provider, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        List<String> readPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
        readPermissions.add("public_profile");
        readPermissions.add("email");
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(readPermissions);

        signInManager = SignInManager.getInstance();
        signInManager.setProviderResultsHandler(this, new SignInProviderResultHandlerImpl());
        signInManager.initializeSignInButton(IdentityProviderType.FACEBOOK, loginButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull final String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull final int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        signInManager.handleRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        signInManager.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (signInManager != null) {
            if (signInManager.getResultHandler().onCancel(this)) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                // Since we are leaving sign-in via back, we can dispose the sign-in manager, since sign-in was cancelled.
                SignInManager.dispose();
            }
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Do you find solution for this issue ?

Comment: no i shift my code to firebase and start learning certification of AWS

Comment: What version of the AWS Mobile SDK are you using?  We've recently updated the AWS Mobile SDK to v2.6.x and the code necessary to do an authentication, including the SignInActivity, is now included in the SDK.

Comment: AWS is very good but I love the google how they explain and simplify the things it really appreciable

Comment: The onSuccess getting called twice is fixed in the latest AWS SDK for Android release. Can you give it a try to the latest version?